# Call function only when log in is made

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I'm trying to implement a login with Facebook JavaScript SDK and PHP, so when user successfully logs in it send an AJAX request to set $_SESSION. To start I used example code from docs, but this just loops the function that sends the AJAX request, where could I get only when user logins for first time.

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        login_FBAuth();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                'into this app.';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                'into Facebook.';
    }
}

function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'secret',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.5'
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id))
        return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function login_FBAuth() {
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'auth/fb_login.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {action: 'login', nombre: response.name},
            success: function (server_response) {
                console.log("Me fui y encontre el servidor");
                console.log("El servidor responde" + server_response);
                if (server_response === 'ok') {
                    console.log('Respuesta correcta');
                    window.location.href = "appmenu.php";
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error en respuesta servidor");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile, email, user_posts, publish_actions" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, that will “loop”, because on the next page load the status will still be `connected` – and you are calling your function from within the fbAsyncInit event as well. I’d suggest you try and subscribe to the [`auth.statusChange` event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.5), and check the current status from the callback function.

Comment: alternatively, read this article, it covers another solution without those weird events: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: @CBroe Why checkLoginState runs every time?, FB docs aren't really precise but I thought that since it says onlogin attribute this would only trigger on login action

Comment: Not that one, but `statusChangeCallback`.